# Sending EMOJIs - php to iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms, emoji

I have a php-to-sms notification system and would like to have emojis in my messages. Unicoide works when I send the message to my email account, but on the iPhone 5 I just see the code. This is the last message i tried:

```
$email_body = "TRY EMOJI: U+1F6A9 - \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA9 - 0xD83D 0xDE0B - &#x1f564;"
```

But no EMOJI in sight...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much php but try sending this way

```
$email_body = "\U0001F6A9"
```

in iOS this will show  the emoji:

```
NSString *pString = @"\U0001F6A9";
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, but just tried that and only got the code.